# React unit-test won't update <input> value

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

***Update:*** Created a new, clearer question for this @ [React: <input> value never updated in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35073662/1846272)

---

I have a React component similar to this:

```
var Example = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text"
      onChange  = {this.props.onChange}
      value     = {this.props.text}
      data-what = {this.props.text} />;
  }
});
```

I have a unit test in which I do this:

1. Use `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` to create the component, using "FIRST" as the `state.text`.
2. Use `Simulate.change` to change the text to "SECOND".

How here's the weirdest thing. If I dump the HTML after each step, I expect to see:

```
<input type="text" data-what="FIRST" value="FIRST">
<input type="text" data-what="SECOND" value="SECOND">
```

…but for some bizarre reason, I keep getting these results:

```
<input type="text" data-what="FIRST" value="FIRST">
<input type="text" data-what="SECOND" value="FIRST">
```

In the second dump, `value` is still "FIRST". What??

Clearly the plumbing is working because `data-what` is correctly changed to "SECOND" but why isn't the value?? Very confused.

Comment: Can you post the `onChange` method of your component? I suspect you want `this.text` to be `this.state.text` and instead of setting `this.text` you should be calling `this.setState({text: 'text'})`.

Comment: What is *this.text*? It should be props or state?

Comment: Oh my mistake, how stupid of me. It's `this.props.text` - I'll update that now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using a [Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

> An `<input>` with `value` set is a controlled component. In a controlled `<input>`, the value of the rendered element will always reflect the `value` prop.

This means that if you want to change the text, you will have to change the `value` property that is supplied to the `<input>`.  Change events will not change the value, and users will be unable to do so either.

I suspect that what you are looking for is the `defaultValue` prop.

```
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text"
      onChange     = {this.onChange}
      defaultValue = {this.text}
      data-what    = {this.text} />;
  }
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my initial code snippet. I've updated it now to show that both `.text` and `.onChange` come from `props`. So it's `value={this.props.value}` with my `this.props.onChange` updating the upstream state which then changes the next `{this.props.value}`. It works fine in the browser without warning. Just the unit test has this bizarre behaviour.

Comment: It might help if you posted the failing unit test in its entirety.

Comment: Agree. I've created a fiddle for this and put it in a new question @ http://stackoverflow.com/q/35073662/1846272