# React: <input> value never updated in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

Say I have a component that renders an `<input type="text" value="whatever">`. If I try to unit test it using `ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change`, the component gets the updated value but then the `value` attribute in the DOM doesn't get the update.

See https://jsfiddle.net/c1ht6zwm/3/

**Edit:** Surely this is a bug. It must be. Raising https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5934.

Comment: Not sure how you test, maybe knowing your setup would help people to assist you.

Comment: I think this issue is around the support of the `outerHTML` property on the dom node.  If you test for `n().value` it is correct after `change`:  `console.log(" After: " + n().value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought `outerHTML` was a dynamic reflection of the tag and its (non-event) properties. It turns out it's its own value that can be out of sync with other properties. As Davin mentioned above, changing `.outerHTML` to `.value` works.